# Different types of residuals revealing different stories on model fit

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, residuals

I have a series of observations as `y_actual` and fit a `glm` model with `binomial` family using `logit` link function using `glm()` of `R`. The series `y_fit` gives the model estimate. Below are my data and fit

```r
y_actual = c(0.136334692, 0.37840196, 0.390388878, 0.332306853, 0.015579242, 
    0.004312221, 0.197257627, 0.003849912, 0.102556055, 0.034236727, 
    0.044338145, 0.323566006, 0.002906722, 0.365485532, 0.497487763, 
    0.407797227, 0.125140868, 0.003000614, 0.010255274, 0.085995523, 
    0.250887837, 0.348495864, 0.490360423, 0.00639617, 0.306278475, 
    0.188225809, 0.084915355, 0.248019023, 0.393584319, 0.248291519, 
    0.102701397, 0.003875779, 0.019110771, 0.141684518, 0.161157541, 
    0.152268462, 0.232824583, 0.211531935, 0.49862286, 0.013384138, 
    0.005328948, 0.002979605, 0.103723205, 0.084474023, 0.012880473, 
    0.405629168, 0.001864907, 0.345550022, 0.43418713, 0.008840066, 
    0.990839128, 0.879488777, 0.874808353, 0.990273562, 0.978276244, 
    0.757710621, 0.653928755, 0.947022794, 0.724590969, 0.996377637, 
    0.735576744, 0.684193226, 1, 0.92141491, 0.857815327, 1, 1, 0.585688824, 
    0.995244609, 0.937017936, 0.721010869, 0.950997678, 1, 0.994234475, 
    0.654585458, 0.595042818, 0.847643574, 0.580531937, 1, 0.947160812, 
    0.978015774, 0.528595922, 0.942787953, 1, 0.833256332, 0.542124525, 
    0.662855368, 0.99478029, 0.929398164, 0.674319383, 0.719835478, 
    0.998391873, 0.629446018, 0.945572679, 0.542700111, 0.849182625, 
    0.571305647, 0.650508505, 0.69688673, 0.632782458)
    
y_fit = c(0.5108746, 0.510187, 0.5119261, 0.5099491, 0.5060829, 0.5114042, 
    0.5058282, 0.5099703, 0.5106101, 0.5115868, 0.513446, 0.5115868, 
    0.5120128, 0.5086123, 0.5142434, 0.5139871, 0.5086469, 0.5107573, 
    0.5120035, 0.5092959, 0.5101969, 0.5101844, 0.512246, 0.5102176, 
    0.5104995, 0.5132078, 0.507861, 0.5096159, 0.5058775, 0.5119135, 
    0.5083143, 0.5092259, 0.512577, 0.5070328, 0.510359, 0.5087454, 
    0.5135267, 0.5106125, 0.5146122, 0.5145157, 0.5083908, 0.5098692, 
    0.5073968, 0.5112421, 0.5122689, 0.5075709, 0.5130123, 0.512024, 
    0.5102805, 0.512763, 0.5135497, 0.5100924, 0.514118, 0.5067507, 
    0.5135497, 0.5100924, 0.514118, 0.5067507, 0.5137501, 0.513939, 
    0.5131861, 0.5127353, 0.5074683, 0.5111746, 0.5088329, 0.5140566, 
    0.5101618, 0.5131737, 0.5095153, 0.514056, 0.5110791, 0.5083455, 
    0.5057883, 0.5072669, 0.5134591, 0.506769, 0.5075491, 0.5094409, 
    0.5137069, 0.5111754, 0.5141377, 0.5128511, 0.5144231, 0.5063635, 
    0.5077987, 0.5071685, 0.5076486, 0.5083421, 0.512321, 0.5145854, 
    0.509603, 0.5074661, 0.5107244, 0.5100801, 0.5123697, 0.5088153, 
    0.5131287, 0.5138794, 0.5076785, 0.5104665)
```

Based on above fit, I estimated `quantile residuals` as below,

```r
set.seed(1); qError = apply(cbind(y_actual, 
    y_fit), 1, function(Y) 
    qnorm(runif(1, pbinom(Y[1] - 1, 1, Y[2]), 
    pbinom(Y[1], 1, Y[2]))))
```

Below is the distribution of this error estimates,

[image]

This histogram is providing some interesting observations. This distribution is highly negatively skewed and **left portion appears **tapering off smoothly**** from the peak at around `-0.10`, however the **right portion falls suddenly**, overall it is not a well behaved bell shaped curve.

I also calculated the `pearson residuals`

```r
pError = apply(cbind(y_actual, y_fit), 1, 
     function(Y) (Y[1] - Y[2]) / 
        sqrt(Y[2] * (1 - Y[2])))
```

The histogram of this residual is as below,

[image]

This histogram reveals completely different story about the model fit. Important difference is that the distribution of `pearson residuals` appears to be somewhat symmetric.

Also, the `response residual` i.e. `actual - fit` is also somewhat symmetrical. Therefore from `response resid` and `pearson resid`, I can infer that the model fit does not have any preference on under-estimation or over-estimation., But if I go with inference from `quantile residual`, I would infer that the model is fairly over-estimation as in this case, distribution of residuals is visibly negatively skewed.

Furthermore, I don't think this issue has anything to do with small sample size (100 observation), because I have taken out a subset of my original data with `5,000` observations, and overall inference remain same.

In this present case, the `y_actual` represents the `success rate` so, I basically fitted a `logistic regression` using `glm` for `ratio` data.

Could you please help me on how can I interpret this scenario with the distribution of `quantile residuals`? I know it is bad fit, but what more can be inferred about the quality of overall model looking at such asymmetrical distribution of `quantile residuals`?

Any insight and pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you fitted a binomial regression directly to the proportions *y_actual*. This doesn't make sense. [Did you get the warning: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm?] If you *plot(y_actual, y_fit)* you can see that there is nothing to learn from these results, other than what you already know -- this is the wrong model for the data, such as it is.

Comment: There is warning. But this is standard approach to fit logistic type regression when response data is fractional type. Some insights can be obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584715/fractional-response-regression-in-r. There you would see, `myglm <- glm(prate ~ mrate + totemp + age + sole, 
             data = df, family = quasibinomial('logit'))` and `myglm1 <- glm(prate ~ mrate + totemp + age + sole, data = df, family = binomial)` would give same estimate (of-course an warning will pop-up in the second case I you stated)